# How to validate if the body of the angular form starts and ends with particular string

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I've to take input from the user that starts with a particular string let's say XYZ and has business data in between and ends with ENDXYZ within the textview and I'm using angular framework for the UI

```
<div class="mb-3 col-md-5">
        <label for="bodyData" class="form-label">Body <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
        <div class=wrapper>
          <textarea class="form-control" formControlName="bodyData"> </textarea>
        </div>
</div>
```

the ts part:

```
bodyData: ['',
        Validators.required
      ]
```

I thought I may use regex for the validation but I'm new to the angular framework so looking if there are any better ways to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1:You can directly check inline:

```
 bodyData: ['',
        Validators.required, Validators.pattern(`your_pattern`)
      ]
```

Method 2: You can create a custom validator and check for your scenario:

In your ts:

```
import {MatchStringValidator} from './match-validator';
....
bodyData: ['',
        Validators.required
      ]
```

Validator:

```
import {Validator} from @angular/forms;

export class MatchStringValidator implements Validator {
    validate(string) {
     // regex logic to match your criteria
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this using inbuilt angular pattern validation.

```
    bodyData: ['', 
    [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(^XYZ.*\.XYZ$)]
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably want https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#pattern

you can also write custom validators. it's just an arrow function with a single control argument, returning an object object with errors if any

```
export declare interface ValidatorFn {
    (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but could you please explain how can I implement it for my case ;--;